# Is it possible to find the partial sum of a series if I know the infinite sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Say, I know the value of $\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}t_r$ (assuming it is convergent) and I want to find out the $n$th partial sum $\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{n}t_r$ for the sequence $\{t_r\}$ from it. Is it possible?

Comment: No. Just add $1$ to one term and subtract $1$ from the next, e.g..

Comment: Can you recover functional values if you know the limit?

Comment: @DavidMitra That would not converge.

Comment: @dtldarek Of course, I meant to only alter two terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2^i}} = 2 = 4 - \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2^i}},
$$

from two series with different partial sums, which converge to the same value.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: So there may not be a unique partial sum?

Comment: @StubbornAtom No, for any convergent sequence you can find another one with different partial sums, but convergent to the same value.

Answer (score 1):

We know the infinite sum :
$$
1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 ... = 1
$$
And its partial sums are : $1/2,\ 3/4,\ 7/8,\ 15/16, ...$
Now I write the almost same sum where I only swap the first and the second term :
$$
1/4+1/2+1/8+1/16 ... = 1
$$
It is still equal to $1$ however the partial sums are now $1/4,\ 3/4,\ 7/8,\ 15/16,...$
So the 1st partial sum cannot be defined. (Same argument applies for any partial sum).